# Filter messages to one group mailbox and not to a second group mailbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am a part of multiple groups in my corporate Gmail account, and would like to filter out all emails from my Inbox that come to group1@gmail.com so that they are marked as read and archived, except when the message is also addressed to group2@gmail.com, in which case I want to keep it in my Inbox.

To summarize:

- If a message is addressed only to group1@gmail.com, filter it out of my inbox
- If a message is addressed only to group2@gmail.com, keep it in the inbox
- If a message is addressed to both group1@gmail.com and group2@gmail.com, keep it in the inbox.

I tried a lot of filters but somehow could not get it right. Is there a way to achieve this ?